# Triggering segue from view controller doesn't load the content on the next ViewController properly

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller, segue

I am currently struggling with an issue where when my segue is triggered the content on the next ViewController either disappears, or takes a while to load.

**This is my code that triggers the segue:**

```
                                userCount = count
                            if userCount != -1{
                                self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "GoToWelcome", sender: self)
                            }
                            if userCount == -1{
                                self.LoadSign.isHidden = true
                                self.createAlert(title: "Error!", message: "Incorrect E-Mail, Please try again")

                            }
```

**This is a screenshot of the two view controllers, when the "Login" button is pressed, the data is checked in the database and if it is correct, the segue is then triggered:**
[IMAGE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YEPPY.png)

**my code for the WelcomeViewController (haven't edited it):**

```
import UIKit

class WelcomeViewController: UIViewController {



@IBOutlet weak var welcomeMessage: UILabel!


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()


}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()

}
```

}

**And here is the code for my LoginViewController (it's quite messy i know)**

```
import UIKit

class LoginScreenController: UIViewController, UITextFieldDelegate {


@IBOutlet weak var LoadSign: UIActivityIndicatorView!
@IBOutlet weak var EMail: UITextField!
@IBOutlet var LoginScreenView: UIView!
@IBAction func LoginButton(_ sender: UIButton) {
            LoadSign.isHidden = false
            let email = EMail.text
            let SQLurl = URL(string:"[myUrl]")

            let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: SQLurl!) { (data, responce, error) in
                if error != nil
                {
                    print("error")

                }
                else
                {
                    if let content = data
                    {
                        do
                        {
                            let myJson = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: content, options: JSONSerialization.ReadingOptions.mutableContainers) as! NSArray


                            var notInDB = false
                            var count = 0
                            var myJsonCount = myJson[count] as! NSDictionary
                            var EmailCount = (myJsonCount["txtEmailAddress"]) as! NSString
                            var userCount = 0






                            while email != EmailCount as String && notInDB == false{
                                count = count+1
                                myJsonCount = myJson[count] as! NSDictionary
                                EmailCount = (myJsonCount["txtEmailAddress"]) as! NSString
                                if count == (myJson.count-1){
                                    print("Error! E-Mail not found in database")
                                    notInDB = true
                                    count = -1


                                }
                            }

                            userCount = count
                            if userCount != -1{
                                self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "GoToWelcome", sender: nil)
                            }
                            if userCount == -1{
                                self.LoadSign.isHidden = true
                                self.createAlert(title: "Error!", message: "Incorrect E-Mail, Please try again")

                            }




                        }
                        catch
                        {

                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            task.resume()


}




override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    EMail.delegate = self
    EMail.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = true



}

func textFieldShouldReturn(_ textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
    textField.resignFirstResponder()
    return true
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()

}

func createAlert (title: String, message: String)
{
    let alert = UIAlertController(title: title, message: message, preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.alert)
    alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Try Again", style: UIAlertActionStyle.default, handler: { (action) in
        alert.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)

    }))
    self.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

}

Are there any reasons why this would be happening?
Thank you!

Comment: Please post the code in `ViewDidLoad` of your Welcome ViewController

Comment: Your sender should be nil, not self

Comment: Just added the code for my welcomeViewController

Comment: Thanks Jacob, i've changed that now but i'm still having the same issue

Comment: You don't have any idea what thread the code in your data task's completion handler might be running and you should not be calling UIKit functions like performSegue from anything other than the main thread.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the problem might be the fact that you're using UIKit from a different thread.  UIKit calls like `performSegue` (and probably what's being called by `self.createAlert` though I can't know from the code you've given) should really only be called from the main thread.

My recommendation would be to handle just stuff related to your request in the dataTask's completion handler then pass control back to the main thread to handle the rest of it.  Here's a sketch based on the code that you sent.  Note that we just get the response data and parse the JSON in the dataTask's background thread, then pass control to a function on the main thread to do the rest of the work:

```
@IBAction func LoginButton(_ sender: UIButton) {
            LoadSign.isHidden = false
            let email = EMail.text
            let SQLurl = URL(string:"[myUrl]")

            let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: SQLurl!) { (data, responce, error) in
                if error != nil
                {
                    print("error")

                }
                else
                {
                    do {
                    // parse the JSON
                    if let myJson = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: content, options: JSONSerialization.ReadingOptions.mutableContainers) as? NSArray {
                        DispatchQueue.main.async { self.handleLoginData(myJson) }
                    } catch {
                        print("JSON Parse error")
                    }
                }
            }
            task.resume()

}

func handleLoginData(myJson: NSArray) {
    do {
        var notInDB = false
        var count = 0
        var myJsonCount = myJson[count] as! NSDictionary
        var EmailCount = (myJsonCount["txtEmailAddress"]) as! NSString
        var userCount = 0

        while email != EmailCount as String && notInDB == false {
            count = count+1
            myJsonCount = myJson[count] as! NSDictionary
            EmailCount = (myJsonCount["txtEmailAddress"]) as! NSString
            if count == (myJson.count-1) {
                print("Error! E-Mail not found in database")
                notInDB = true
                count = -1
            }
        }

        userCount = count
        if userCount != -1 {
            self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "GoToWelcome", sender: nil)
        } else {
            self.LoadSign.isHidden = true
            self.createAlert(title: "Error!", message: "Incorrect E-Mail, Please try again")
        }
    }
    catch
    {

    }
}
```

You my have to play with the code a bit to get it to work, but notice how it leaves the data handling for the request with the request and separates out the work for your problem domain to another function.  When working with asynchronous blocks try to keep all of the work done in any particular block related to just one task.

Comment: It worked! took a bit of editing but it's perfect now.. thank you so much!